# How do I make all class member functions write to the same file in C++?

Tags: c++, function, class, output, ofstream

```
ofstream outPatron;
outPatron.open("patronRec.txt")
```

I am trying to make it so that all of my different functions within the class Patron can use this ofstream to write to a file which will contain all of the data for each patron.
I have tried putting this code in the class definition, which leads to an error as such things can only be declared within functions. (or so I assume, considering that that's the only way I got it to work) I tried putting it inside a function definition within the class definition, and every time that function ran, it erased the entire file and started again with only the newest iteration.
Finally, I tried putting this in main, but it wouldn't even compile, saying that each time I use outPatron in the class functions, it's an undeclared identifier.
This is the function I need to use it in.

```
void Patron::AddPatron(string a, int b, int c, int d) {
SetName(a);
SetID(b);
SetFineBalance(c);
SetBooksOut(d);
count++;

outPatron << "Name: " << Patron::GetName() << endl;
outPatron << "ID: " << Patron::GetID() << endl;
outPatron << "Fine Balance: " << Patron::GetFineBalance() << endl;
outPatron << "Books Out: " << Patron::GetBooksOut() << endl << "-------------------" << endl;
```

}

Comment: you open with append mode, or do not close and reopen it.

Comment: Have a [beginner book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282), and read the info on [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) and [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) of course.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing `ofstream outPatron; outPatron.open("patronRec.txt")` to `ofstream outPatron("patronRec.txt")`.